# Laravel 5 Multi-Tenancy App on Fortrabbit

Tags: php, laravel-5, multi-tenant, fortrabbit

Currently migrating Laravel 5 multi-tenancy application on to Fortrabbit.
My account type is Floppy [ A minimal setup for a development environment, multi-staging, playground or even for a small production.]

Single database works perfectly fine, however current grants permitting from creating new databases.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'my-app'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 
'*12345678901234567890' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 5 

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX,
 ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW 
ON `my-app`.* TO 'my-app'@'%'
```

Is it possible to have multiple databases on Floppy preset?

Please can anyone suggest solution to this issue ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

*I replied to your private ticket already, but it's worth to answer public:*

You can not simply create another database, since there is only one database included and all limits, metrics and migration processes interact with this single database.

This means a setup with multiple databases will not work at fortrabbit.

You may book a RDS database instances at AWS to get more flexibility.

However, most mutli-tenancy applications work with a single database, by adding the "customer_id" to each table to put it simply.

Cheers
Oli